# VBA Access SQL query issue

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba

I need your help please, I have a serious problem in my SQL request, it should show me the list of patients of the service `Nephro` but it shows me the list of all patients, so I think the SQL query does not work at all

This is the code :

```
Private Sub btnConnexion_Click()

Dim Categ As Integer
Dim Service As String
Dim IdProf As Integer

Dim db As DAO.Database
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset

Dim strSQL As String
Set db = CurrentDb


'vérification que l'utilisater a bien entrer e login et le mot de passe
Me.txtlogin.SetFocus
If IsNull(Me.txtlogin) Then
MsgBox "svp entrer votre login ", vbInformation, "login required "
Me.txtlogin.SetFocus
ElseIf IsNull(Me.txtmdp) Then
MsgBox "svp entrer votre mots de passe ", vbInformation, "mdp required "
Me.txtmdp.SetFocus
Else
'vérification que le login et le mdp sont corrects
If (IsNull(DLookup("login", "dbo_Authentification", "login='" & Me.txtlogin.Value & "'"))) Or _
    (IsNull(DLookup("mdp", "dbo_Authentification", "mdp='" & Me.txtmdp.Value & "'")))    Then
    MsgBox "login ou mdp incorrect"
Else
'récupération de l'IdCatégorie dans Categ, pour préciser les sessions des acteurs selon  leurs catégories professionneles
    Categ = DLookup("IdCategorie", "dbo_Professionnel", "IdProfessionnel = " &   DLookup("IdCompte", "dbo_Authentification", "login='" & Me.txtlogin.Value & "'"))
    'DoCmd.Close
    If Categ = 3 Then
        DoCmd.OpenForm "role"
        Else
        DoCmd.OpenForm "ListingPatients"

        'Service récupère le service du professionnel authentifié pour l'afficher à l'entete du formulaire "ListingPatients"
        Service = Nz(DLookup("IntituleServ", "dbo_Service", "IdService = " & DLookup("IdService", "dbo_Professionnel", "IdProfessionnel = " & DLookup("IdCompte", "dbo_Authentification", "login='" & Me.txtlogin.Value & "'"))), "inconnu")
        Forms![ListingPatients]![txtIntituleServ] = Service



        strSQL = "SELECT dbo_Patient.*, dbo_Service.IntituleServ, dbo_HospitalisatAcuelle.lit, dbo_Professionnel.IdProfessionnel, dbo_HospitalisatAcuelle.DateEntree, dbo_HospitalisatAcuelle.DateSortie FROM dbo_Service INNER JOIN ((dbo_Professionnel INNER JOIN dbo_Authentification ON dbo_Professionnel.IdProfessionnel = dbo_Authentification.IdCompte) INNER JOIN (dbo_Patient INNER JOIN (dbo_HospitalisatAcuelle INNER JOIN dbo_DonneePatientActuelles ON dbo_HospitalisatAcuelle.IdHosp = dbo_DonneePatientActuelles.IdHosp) ON dbo_Patient.IdPatient = dbo_DonneePatientActuelles.IdPatient) ON dbo_Professionnel.IdProfessionnel = dbo_HospitalisatAcuelle.IdProfessionnel) ON dbo_Service.IdService = dbo_Professionnel.Idservice WHERE (((dbo_HospitalisatAcuelle.DateEntree)<=Now()) AND ((dbo_HospitalisatAcuelle.DateSortie)>Now())) OR (((dbo_HospitalisatAcuelle.DateSortie) Is Null))"
        strSQL = strSQL & " AND [dbo_Service]![IntituleServ] = ' " & Service & " ' "


       Set rs = db.OpenRecordset(strSQL)

       rs.Close

       Set rs = Nothing
       Set db = Nothing
   End If
End If
End If

End Sub
```

Thank you very much

Comment: Remove spaces when make Service name in query: instead of `= ' " & Service & " ' "` use `= '" & Service & "' "`

Comment: Hi, the result is the same even removing spaces

Comment: `AND [dbo_Service]![IntituleServ]` -> `AND [dbo_Service].[IntituleServ]`

Comment: thank you for your reply but it doesn't work :(

Comment: Try creating a Query object in MS-Access with the SQL definition of strSQL, first without and then with the final AND clause using a named parameter. This will enable you to make sure that the SQL query is correct before attempting to use it in the VBA routine.

Comment: Thank you @Peter, This is what I did but the "where" still doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

Check the WHERE clause of your VBA recordset SQL query. Your parenthesis set may be out of order. As you can see dbo_Service![IntituleServ] field is not contained but hangs out on  an OR statement.

Consider moving the last parenthesis after the DateSortie >=Now() to after DateSortie Is Null.

```
WHERE 

(
 (
   (dbo_HospitalisatAcuelle.DateEntree)<=Now()
 ) AND 

 (
   (dbo_HospitalisatAcuelle.DateSortie)>Now()
 )
) 

OR 
 (
  (
   (dbo_HospitalisatAcuelle.DateSortie) Is Null
  )
 )

AND 

[dbo_Service]![IntituleServ] = ' " & Service & " ' "
```

Comment: strSQL = "SELECT dbo_Patient.*, .... FROM dbo_Service .... WHERE (((dbo_Service.IntituleServ)= '" & Service & "') AND ((dbo_HospitalisatAcuelle.DateEntree)<=Now()) AND ((dbo_HospitalisatAcuelle.DateSortie)>Now())) OR (((dbo_HospitalisatAcuelle.DateSortie) Is Null));"

This request is generated by the graphic interface using where ... = "Nephro" ! so all what I did is to replace the static "Nephro" by the variable "& Service &" but it still chows me all the list "Nephro + Cardio" ! have you an idea ?

Comment: Did you change the parenthesis as I specified? The reason all patient records show may be because the OR forces logic to follow either condition: 1) first two conditions (DateEntree<=Now() & DateSortie>Now) **OR** 2) last two conditions (DateSortie Is Null AND IntituleServ='Nephro'). Not both together!

Comment: Yes I did, this is the new WHERE after modification : 
    WHERE (((dbo_HospitalisatAcuelle.DateEntree)<=Now())   AND((dbo_HospitalisatAcuelle.DateSortie)>Now())) OR (((dbo_HospitalisatAcuelle.DateSortie) Is Null)) AND [dbo_Service]![IntituleServ] = ' " & Service & " ' ;"

but still show all the patients :/

Comment: Forgive me, but I see no change from previous WHERE clause. I even went back to your original code and compared. Simply move the very last parenthesis before the _OR_ --> after _Null_. There should be 3 parenthesis after Null. Try that and see.

Comment: .... >Now()) OR (((dbo_HospitalisatAcuelle.DateSortie) Is Null)));"

Unfortunately, the problem remains :(

Comment: I see a semicolon at the end which means you are leaving out the IntituleServ condition. Another question - where are you using the rs VBA recordset? In above code, you open it and then immediately close it. Wherever you see the results (i.e., form or report RecordSource, listbox/combobox RowSource, etc.) may help.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply, the problem is that this is the first time that I use SQL query in VBA ACCESS, so I just typed what I found in tutorial about the recordset, so I'm not sure that I puted it in the correct form ! can you please help me ? thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

The DB object doesn't support queries, it can only be used to open entire tables.

Instead, use a `QueryDef` object. So the following code:

```
Set rs = db.OpenRecordset(strSQL)
```

should be

```
'up at the top
Dim qdf as QueryDef
'... code

Set qdf = db.CreateQueryDef("",strSQL)
set rs = qdf.OpenRecordSet(DbOpenSnapshot)
'... at the bottom
qdf.close
```

Also, there is a problem with your SQL the WHERE part should probably be

```
" WHERE (dbo_HospitalisatAcuelle.DateEntree<=Now() " & _
" AND (dbo_HospitalisatAcuelle.DateSortie>Now() OR dbo_HospitalisatAcuelle.DateSortie Is Null)) " & _
" AND [dbo_Service].[IntituleServ] = ' " & Service & " ' "
```

(note the placement of the brackets `()`)

Comment: Hi @serakfalcon thank you for your reply, I get the Error "Query must have at least one destination field" in the line "Set rs = qdf.OpenRecordset(dbOpenSnapshot)"  ... is this syntax is now good ? 

    strSQL = "SELECT ... WHERE dbo_HospitalisatAcuelle.DateEntree<=Now() AND (dbo_HospitalisatAcuelle.DateSortie>Now() OR dbo_HospitalisatAcuelle.DateSortie Is Null)) AND [dbo_Service].[IntituleServ] = ' " & Service & " ' ;"

Comment: the syntax looks correct. can you post the entire SQL you are trying? and do all the tables/queries you are using have the fields you expect them to?

Comment: Please can you take a look on the original file, to see the MLD and better understand the problem please 

https://www.mediafire.com/?wz3z9vv53ppp5ph

Comment: I can't open that file, sorry.

Comment: Ok i understand, so what should I show you please ? it's a school project so I need the help please

Comment: what is the full SQL statement you are now trying

Comment: I can't post it in a comment because it's too long ! I will cut it in two parts :

Comment: strSQL = "SELECT dbo_Patient.*, dbo_Service.IntituleServ, dbo_HospitalisatAcuelle.lit, dbo_Professionnel.IdProfessionnel, dbo_HospitalisatAcuelle.DateEntree, dbo_HospitalisatAcuelle.DateSortie FROM dbo_Service INNER JOIN ((dbo_Professionnel INNER JOIN dbo_Authentification ON dbo_Professionnel.IdProfessionnel = dbo_Authentification.IdCompte) INNER JOIN (dbo_Patient INNER JOIN (dbo_HospitalisatAcuelle INNER JOIN dbo_DonneePatientActuelles ON dbo_HospitalisatAcuelle.IdHosp =

Comment: dbo_DonneePatientActuelles.IdHosp) ON dbo_Patient.IdPatient = dbo_DonneePatientActuelles.IdPatient) ON dbo_Professionnel.IdProfessionnel = dbo_HospitalisatAcuelle.IdProfessionnel) ON dbo_Service.IdService = dbo_Professionnel.Idservice WHERE dbo_HospitalisatAcuelle.DateEntree<=Now() AND (dbo_HospitalisatAcuelle.DateSortie>Now() OR dbo_HospitalisatAcuelle.DateSortie Is Null)) AND [dbo_Service].[IntituleServ] = ' " & Service & " ' ;"

Comment: ok what happens if you make a new query and paste that info in the SQL view (replace `'" & Service "'`) with a value you know exists

Comment: This shows an error "extra ) in query expression...." but the sql query that I posted in the question works when I replace service by ="Nephro" !

Comment: so the query should work then, is the Service variable set to something reasonable when you run the code